# Hide and show comments

Tags: r, comments

I'm writing all my scripts on .R file using R for mac. It is convenient to me because there are colors to highlight the type of commands.

I have a many comments following the # symbol that are useful when I forget about the meaning of my script but they tend to blur my script so that it gets harder to find a given command line.

Is there a way to hide and show these comments ? (Using the programm I'm currently using or another one). What would you suggest as the best program to write R script ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If the comments blur your script, you are probably using too many comments. Try and cut your code up into functions with descriptive names  (`fit_model_and_predict`), you could also go further and cut your code up into several files with sets of functions, or even write your own pacakages. This greatly reduces the need for comments. Comments should be limited to only those things that are not obvious from the code, e.g. `i = i + 1 # increase i` is a bad comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RStudio supports [code folding](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/code_folding). You can standardize your comment blocks so that they are recognized as code blocks.

For example, enter this into your RStudio editor

```
#=======================================================
# this is a comment block
# more comments here
# comments upon comments
```

and then press `Alt`+`L` to fold, and `Alt`+`Shift`+`L` to unfold.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/) for mac. One of the greatest code writing environment for R there is.

You can also try Emacs, which is more like old-fashioned command line editor. You can find a good guide [here](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/using-emacs-to-work-with-r/).